# to be ended up, to be arrived: regionalism?

Tags: dialects, auxiliary-verbs

I recently saw the phrase "how I been ended up here" in a work of fiction (someone showed me the phrase on a page and I can't remember the title at the moment, but I was told that it was set in  20th century America) and I'm wondering if there's an American regional dialect where **to be ended up** or "to be arrived" is still used nowadays.

Compare [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=SH8TlI8Bu1YC&pg=PA162&dq=%22been%20arrived%20here%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI4LW09_fOAhWGDpAKHbvDAP4Q6AEISTAI#v=onepage&q=%22been%20arrived%20here%22&f=false).

Comment: I doubt very much your cited usage reflects any kind of dialect or regionalism. It's just a (perfectly credible, imho) one-off coinage which uses the passive to emphasize that the speaker had ***little or no control*** over the processes that eventually led him to his current situation. The omission of ***have/had*** before ***been*** is indicative of AAVE, assuming you transcribed that part accurately.

Comment: ...if it's from [Squaring the Circle: The Circle of Light](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22has+been+ended+up+here%22) by Niel Hancock, my guess is the speaker simply isn't a native Anglophone in the first place (he says *since **we has** been ended up here in this place*).

Comment: ...and [here are dozens](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will+end+you+up+in%22) of "transitive" examples with ***will end you up in** [some undesirable final state]*.

Comment: In *how I been ended up here,* the *been* is probably an AAVE verb tense which means something subtly different than *how I ended up here.* [According to Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English#Tense_and_aspect) it's a pre-recent verb tense, which means he ended up here some time ago.